# Run a desktop application by a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created a windows service who check if a specific application is running or not and if that application was not running before or it was closed by user , the service try to run it again.

but here is the problem , that the service work correctly on windows 8 , and when I close that windows application , the service try to start it again , but this service does not work in windows server 2008 R2 and when I close the application  , the service does not start the application

is there any body to help me on this ?

I wrote the application with Dot Net framework 4.5 and VS 2013

**Update 1 :**

```
Tick = new Timer();
Tick.Interval = 3000;
Tick.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.Tick_Elapsed);
Tick.Start();
```

/////

```
 public void Tick_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
       {
           List<IOTools.AppStruct> applist = new List<IOTools.AppStruct>();
           applist = IOTools.GetApplicationList();

           var NotRun = applist.Select(c => new { AppName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(c.AppName).ToLower() })
               .Except(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Select(r => new { AppName = r.ProcessName.ToLower() + ".exe"}));

           var FinallList = from app in applist
                            join nr in NotRun on System.IO.Path.GetFileName(app.AppName).ToLower() equals nr.AppName
                   select app;

           foreach (var app in FinallList)
           {
               Process.LaunchChildProcess(app.AppName, app.args);
           }
       }
```

Comment: There really isn't any possible way we could guess what the problem is without seeing your code, etc.  This question will probably be closed as "too broad" unless you modify it.

Comment: @roryap , Ook , let me to put my code ;-) ASAP

Comment: Also, if you think it has to do with different windows versions, you should tag it accordingly

Comment: @roryap , Yes I think windows versions causes this problem , can you provide me what tag should I add to my question ?

Comment: What is the `Process.LaunchChildProcess`?

Comment: Check event viewer. By the description, my first suspicion is permissions.